# sort an NSArray of CLLocation objects

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array of `CLLocation` object. I would like to order this array with the distance to the user current location.

I know that I can calculate the distance between the user's location and each `CLLocation` object and then order it with this distance. Is there any other solution which doesn't need calculations? Thanks.

Comment: How do you want to obtain the distance without calculating it? What's so hard on applying Pithagoras' theorem in a for loop?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i know that it's not very difficult but i was looking for something easier like comparing just the latitudes or longitudes :). Anyway, let's try the first methode

Comment: CLLocation has the convenient [distanceFromLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126-CH3-SW18) method.  Use that with NSArray's sortedArrayUsingComparator and it should be relatively easy.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina I was just going to suggest that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get the distance without calculating it. But the calculation is fairly simple, and you have to do it only once in the comparator block.

```
[array sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id o1, id o2) {
    CLLocation *l1 = o1, *l2 = o2;

    CLLocationDistance d1 = [l1 distanceFromLocation:userLocation];
    CLLocationDistance d2 = [l2 distanceFromLocation:userLocation];
    return d1 < d2 ? NSOrderedAscending : d1 > d2 ? NSOrderedDescending : NSOrderedSame;
}];
```